# 'str' object cannot be interpreted as integer error in text scraping method

Tags: python, web-scraping, text

I'm having some trouble with a method for a text scraper that I'm writing. When I test my method within my text_scraper.py file it works fine and prints out each line from a chosen .txt file with each line having a certain num_words.

```
    def numbered_words(self, text_file, num_words):
        '''
        :param text_file: a list of strings of plain text
                num_words: number of words that eqch string should
                    be in length
        :return: a list of strings of equal number of words
        TODO: Index out of range error. Just go through the code by hand and you'll find the error
        '''
        # Split each line in the text_file into individual words
        line_list = [] # list of individual words

        for line in text_file:
            split_line = line.split()
            line_list.append(split_line) # List is mutable

        split_text_list = [item for sublist in line_list for item in sublist]
        print(type(split_text_list))
        for i in range(0, len(split_text_list), num_words):
            # TODO: TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
            #       I think it has to do with the .txt file
            # Join each iterated group of words. If words left over at the end
            # they will be put into separate string
            end = i + num_words
            return ' '.join(split_text_list[i:end])
```

However, when I try to import text_scraper.py into a test file, it doesn't cooperate and produces the following traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/School/Programming/MyPrograms/PythonPractice/practice.py", line 19, in <module>
    results2 = et2.extract(text_f_name)
  File "/Users/Desktop/School/Programming/MyPrograms/PythonPractice/extract_text.py", line 47, in extract
    numbered_text = scraper.numbered_words(raw_text, grouping_number)
  File "/Users/Desktop/School/Programming/MyPrograms/PythonPractice/text_scraper.py", line 41, in numbered_words
    for i in range(0, len(split_text_list), num_words):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Extract_text.py is just another file that I've gathered other scraping classes, ones for scraping pdfs and web pages. Whereas practice.py is where I'm choosing to test my extract_text and text_scraper classes. Here's my actual code in my practice.py file.

```
from extract_text import ExtractText
from web_scraper import WebScraper
from text_scraper import TextScraper

f_name = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_panda'

text_f_name = 'eighty_days.txt'
# Instantiate web scraper
scraper = WebScraper(f_name)
# pdf = 'Alexander the Great.pdf'
# Q: Why is this not callable? Q: What is the venv?
et = ExtractText(method = 'web')
results = et.extract(f_name, header1 ='Giant Panda')
for result in results:
    print(result.text)

et2 = ExtractText(method = 'plain_text')

results2 = list(et2.extract(text_f_name))
for line in results2:
    print(line)
```

I tried several things. Including double checking that split_text_list was a list, changing my
yield ' '.join(split_text_list[i:end]) to return, redefining the "end" variable in terms of the index of i. But nothing's changed and the issue keeps coming from that for loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked if num_words is an int?

Comment: You know what it was? I was requesting user input in one of my other files, extract_text.py, in order to ask the user how many words they want grouped. I forgot that a user input request doesn't consider an integer input to be an integer. It sees it as a string. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Tbh I had a feeling it was something to do with num_words but I kept on looking at my function definition instead of my user input

Answer (score 0):

### The error received:

> TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

### Traceback:

> File "/Users/Desktop/School/Programming/MyPrograms/PythonPractice/extract_text.py", line 47, in extract
> numbered_text = scraper.numbered_words(raw_text, grouping_number)
> File "/Users/Desktop/School/Programming/MyPrograms/PythonPractice/text_scraper.py", line 41, in numbered_words

The `for loop` : `for i in range(0, len(split_text_list), num_words):` received this error because `num_words` was being passed as a `string`, rather than the expected type `int`. `num_words` expects an `int` in this `for loop` because it is the step value. (see 'References')

### Solution:

Convert `num_words` into an `int` before passing it in as an argument for `numbered_words()` function. ( i.e. `int(num_words)` )

### References:

Documentation for Python `for loop`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range